# CoreBluetooth iOS api changes: BLE 4.0 vs BLE 4.2

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy-4.2

I am trying to get under the hood of BLE 4.2 and how this affects the product design as well as iPhone development.

- A: What are the CoreBluetooth API changes to support BLE 4.2?

  - Has there been any?
- B: How is device pairing implemented in 4.0 and how is it implemented in 4.2?

I understand that one of the main **security improvements** in BLE 4.2 is that it does not use the pairing key to generate a set of public/private encryption keys. However I haven't seen an example yet of this and would like to understand it a bit better.

- C: Is there a security/pairing CoreBluetooth API in iOS?

  - Does this differ for 4.0 to 4.2 devices?

Comment: A: none that I know of. B: pairing is handled by iOS when an encrypted attribute is accessed C: no, there is no pairing API in Core Bluetooth

Comment: Mmhh... I need to look into the firmware side then. As at the moment I have been using GATT profiles that are not encrypted. Haven't found a good example yet that uses encryption on client side. If you have  a link to one would help (or some code snippets).

Comment: As far as I know you just configure the attribute with the encrypted property on the peripheral and iOS does the rest; prompts the user to pair with a PIN and establishes the keys. You don't need to do anything special in your CBCentral.

Comment: HI Paulw11 and MM24 : could you please help me anything for this problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710499/iphone-8-or-higher-ble-5-0-with-wahoo-tickr-heart-rate-measure-not-working